# Trigger Insert & Update insert from table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need a Trigger to insert & update from picture

1 - If the row was updated row of the table is stored in the users table userupdate

2 - If the row was added to the users table where the row is stored in the table userinsert

Please write the image to the Trigger

http://uploadax.com/images/29273921895184292278.jpg

Comment: This is not the codewriting service.  BUt I'll give you a hint. Do not assume only one row is processed by the trigger or you will have data integrity problems.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two separate triggers.  One for ON UPDATE and one for ON INSERT.